# How can I change geckodriver's proxy?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I need change Firefox driver's proxy when I start code because my project creates a lot of accounts in any sites and some sites blocks it for example Instagram and I need change proxy for this issue. How I can do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changing the settings from FireFox Profile is probably what you are looking for**
`webdriver.FirefoxProfile()`

```py
        from selenium import webdriver

        # myProxy = "127.0.0.1:9150"
        myProxy = "192.168.103.1:1081"
        ip, port = myProxy.split(":")
        fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        fp.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
        fp.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', ip)
        fp.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', int(port))
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
```

From there you can change settings easily by calling .set_preference()

**Another way for proxies from the [official doc](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/http_proxies/)**

```py
from selenium import webdriver

PROXY = "<HOST:PORT>"
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": PROXY,
    "ftpProxy": PROXY,
    "sslProxy": PROXY,
    "proxyType": "MANUAL",

}

with webdriver.Firefox() as driver:
    # Open URL
    driver.get("https://selenium.dev")
```

[Selenium faq doc](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/faq.html)

Comment: Hello, it worked but I need ready proxies and automaticly changing it on code. So i need change proxy when i restart code.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, but this article might able to help you [Multiple Proxy Servers in Selenium Web-driver Python](https://medium.com/ml-book/multiple-proxy-servers-in-selenium-web-driver-python-4e856136199d)

Comment: Hello, I used this code but my proxy doesn't change. Im seeing my origianl ip in ip checker website :( I didn't bind my driver is that makes a problem?

Comment: Probably, did you try the 2nd newer method I wrote?```webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX['proxy']```  ?

Comment: Yes, but driver doesn't open link. I just see browser opened.